# webhook facebook plugin comments nofitications when user edits comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, plugins

I am using plugin facebookcomment and set up webhook for receiving new comments and replies comments.

I have noticed that when user edits his comment, there is no notification sending.

My questions are:

1- Is there any parameters to add or to put in configuration in the comment plugin and then users are not able to edit theirs comments, I mean "editing comment" is not allowing

2-Is there any configuration in the application facebook to put and then we can receive notifications webhook when user edits his comment.

Thanks a lot for your replies

Comment: No, and No. Neither of those things is possible.

Comment: ok and ok thanks a lot hihihi